# React rendering 4 components with single list of user information instead of one user

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app that I'm building with a list of users. I've mapped through the user Array and am able to display each user's name so that it can be clicked on. I then pass the props down to a "UserCard" component where which that component is supposed to render the user's info. This is happening uniquely and working just fine, however the user is being displayed 4 times(Lenght of the array)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import UserCard from './UserCard.jsx';

class User extends Component{
onClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const {updateUserId, user} = this.props;
    updateUserId(user);
}
render(){
const {user, activeUser, userIdToShow} = this.props;
const active = user === activeUser ? 'active' : '';

return(
    <li className={active} role='presentation'>
        <a onClick={() => this.props.updateUserId(this.props.users.Id)}>
            {this.props.users.Name}
        </a>
        {userIdToShow ? <UserCard 
            key={this.props.users.Id}
            user={this.props.People[userIdToShow-1]}/> : null}
    </li>
   )
   }
}

 export default User;
```

And the user list (parent compenent) looks something like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import User from './User.jsx';

class UserList extends Component{    
render(){
    return(
        <ul className='nav nav-tabs nav-justified'> 
            {this.props.People.map(person => {
                return <User 
                    users={person}
                    key={person.Id}
                    {...this.props}
                />
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
}

export default UserList;
```

Any feedback would be appreciated. I'll try and get my app up on a JSBin or Fiddle. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You use key attribute on UserCard. Key is a 'keyword' attribute in react and using it outside of child collections might lead to a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

```
class User extends Component{
      // 1. use a state to show/hide user
      constructor(props){
           super(props);
           this.state = {show:false};
      }
      // 2. add a show user that will be called in on-click
      showUser(){
          this.setState({show:true});
      }

      return(
        <li className={active} role='presentation'>
         // 3. update the state of show in on-click
         <a onClick={() => this.props.updateUserId(this.props.users.Id);this.showUser();}>
          {this.props.users.Name}
        </a>
        // 4. use state to display the user card
       {this.state.show ? <UserCard 
        key={this.props.users.Id}
        user={this.props.People[userIdToShow-1]}/> : null}
   </li>
   )
  }
 }
```

Comment: Essentially that is the same thing I'm doing with "updateUserId" That function is defined and set on State at the outer most parent level. It selects the user id where the user gets clicked on and display's that user's info. The problem is that it displays it 4 times (length of the array). This was a great idea though I could try and implement something similar to this with what I have already. also, can you make two function calls on one "click event"?? that seems weird.

Comment: My full app is up at : https://github.com/ryanhca/react-challenge-users if you're interested in seeing how the whole thing is structured.

Comment: You could extract the two function calls into a one function and call that function. The state should be isolated for the specific user, then only that specific user will be shown. When the parent component state is changed it would send the same state (true) to all the user components and will display all the users. In this case as you need to show a specifc user, the state should be within the user component.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply doing the following to my code:

```
return(
  <li className={active} role='presentation'>
    <a onClick={() => this.props.updateUserId(this.props.users.Id)}>
        {this.props.users.Name}
    </a>
    {userIdToShow ((I had no check against the "Clicked on User's ID here))? <UserCard 
        key={this.props.users.Id}
        user={this.props.People[userIdToShow-1]}/> : null}
  </li>
)
```

Because I had no check, it would render the card four times with the same properties on it. I needed to do this

```
return(
  <li className={active} role='presentation'>
    <a onClick={() => this.props.updateUserId(this.props.users.Id)}>
        {this.props.users.Name}
    </a>
    {userIdToShow === this.users.props.Id ? <UserCard 
        key={this.props.users.Id}
        user={this.props.People[userIdToShow-1]}/> : null}
  </li>
)
```

And that worked like a charm.